# calculate google maps tile boundary coordinates

Tags: google-maps, mercator

I've made a lot of searches and found some useful resources but still having problems about calculation.

I want to calculate NE and SW coordinates for a specific tile.

This is my way :

```
Zoom = 11
x = 1188 
y = 767

number of tile = 2 ^ 11 (equals 2048)
angle1 = 360 / 2048
longitude = (1188 * angle1) - 180
```

it works correct.

But latitude part is not :

```
angle2 = 170.1022575596 / (2048/2)
latitude = ((2048 / 2) - 767) * angle2
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The solution you are looking for is this:

```
z = 11
x = 1188 
y = 767

pi = 3.14159

alon1 = (x /2^z)*360.0 - 180.0
alon2 = ((x+1) /2^z)*360.0 - 180.0

an   = pi-2*pi*y/2^z
alat1 = 180.0/pi*atan(0.5*(exp(an)-exp(-an)))
an   = pi-2*pi*(y+1)/2^z
alat2 = 180.0/pi*atan(0.5*(exp(an)-exp(-an)))
```

And you get the NW (alon1,alat1) & SE (alon2,alat2) coordinates for this specific tile.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I was looking for!

In java if anyone want to copy/paste:
int tilesAtZoomLevel = 1 << zoom;
double alon1 = ((double)x /tilesAtZoomLevel)*360.0 - 180.0;
double alon2 = (((double)x+1) /tilesAtZoomLevel)*360.0 - 180.0;
double an1   = Math.PI-2*Math.PI*y/tilesAtZoomLevel;
double alat1 = 180.0/Math.PI*Math.atan(0.5*(Math.exp(an1)-Math.exp(-an1)));
double an2   = Math.PI-2*Math.PI*(y+1)/tilesAtZoomLevel;
double alat2 = 180.0/Math.PI*Math.atan(0.5*(Math.exp(an2)-Math.exp(-an2)));

Answer (score 0):

Here I want to share a **python** version answer.

PS: [the last answer includes ***matlab*** and ***java*** [implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40521739/7194271)]

```
from math import atan, exp
z = 18.
x = 223576.
y = 101583.
pi = 3.1415926

alon1 = (x /pow(2.,z))*360.0 - 180.0
alon2 = ((x+1) /pow(2.,z))*360.0 - 180.0

an   = pi-2.*pi*y/pow(2.,z)
alat1 = 180.0/pi*atan(0.5*(exp(an)-exp(-an)))
an   = pi-2.*pi*(y+1)/pow(2.,z)
alat2 = 180.0/pi*atan(0.5*(exp(an)-exp(-an)))
print(alon1,alat1,alon2,alat2)
```